# Update variables data using Set State

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to update the two variables when app resumes, the variables are minutes and hours. Right now when i resume the app the values don't get updated.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
    dateTimeNow = DateTime.parse('${prefs.getString('startTime')}');
    startedDateTime = DateTime.now();

    minutes = startedDateTime.difference(dateTimeNow).inMinutes % 60;
    hours = startedDateTime.difference(dateTimeNow).inHours;

    if (minutes < 0) {
      minutes = 0;
    }
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        print("Inactive");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        print("Paused");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        print('resumed');
        setState(() { // trying to updated
          minutes = startedDateTime.difference(dateTimeNow).inMinutes % 60;
          hours = startedDateTime.difference(dateTimeNow).inHours;
        });
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I recommend viewing the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49869873/flutter-update-widgets-on-resume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are not updating the `startedDateTime` value. You only set it during the first initialization of the state but you are not updating the value later. Meaning, even after updating your values with `didChangeAppLifecycleState`, the `startedDateTime` is still the same, hence the `minutes` or `hours` values remain the same.

Try to do something like this:

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state); // <-- Add this as well
  switch (state) {
    <...>
    case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
      print('resumed');
      setState(() {
        // trying to updated
        startedDateTime = DateTime.now(); // <-- Update the value
        minutes = startedDateTime.difference(dateTimeNow).inMinutes % 60;
        hours = startedDateTime.difference(dateTimeNow).inHours;
      });
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly add `super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);` at the end of `didChangeAppLifecycleState()` method as like this:

```
 void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        print("Inactive");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        print("Paused");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        print('resumed');
        setState(() { // trying to updated
          minutes = startedDateTime.difference(dateTimeNow).inMinutes % 60;
          hours = startedDateTime.difference(dateTimeNow).inHours;
        });
        break;
    }
        super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  }
```

And also override the dispose method:

```
void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: Sorry but unfortunately this isn't working